# Unknown complex identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fractions

I have found a particular solution to a second order differential equation to be:
$$\left(\frac{10}{(1+i)}\right)e^{ix}$$
However, the solution is not the problem, my problem is that I have used Wolfram alpha to simplify the coefficient and found that:
$$\left(\frac{10}{(1+i)}\right)=5-5i.$$
I do not understand how they are equal. I vaguely remember some identity regarding -i, which I'm assuming is how I simplify, if someone could let me know how I get from LHS to RHS that'd be great. Thanks

Comment: Just multiply by the conjugate of $1 + i$ both the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $$\frac{10}{1+i}=\frac{10(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}=\frac{10(1-i)}{2}=5(1-i).$$

Answer (score 0):

If you do no remember that you have to multiply by the conjugated quantity (the preferred method anyway, since it works also with square roots), you can always try direct identification:

$\dfrac{10}{1+i}=a+ib\iff 10=(a+ib)(1+i)=(a-b)+i(a+b)$

So you solve the system $\begin{cases}a-b=10\\a+b=0\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}a=5\\b=-5\end{cases}\quad$ and find $5-5i$.